# People picker allow multiple selection

Tags: infopath, people-picker, multiple-values

I have a custom InfoPath form with Subordinate people picker field where I have to put multiple users to take an action. people picker field accepts only one single value. From the properties i check the option (Allow multiple selection) but that does not add any change. I see that we can add the people picker inside a repeating table but that also does not work. Can anyone tell me what can I do.

Comment: can anyone help! I want to use the associate task list with the field subordinates to send an approval task to them.

Comment: Can you help on that please @Mohamed El-Qassas

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the list that this infopath form is connected to doesn't have "allow multiple selections" activated.

1. Open settings for your list
2. select the people picker field you created in infopath
   [image]
3. select yes under "allow multiple selections" and click ok
   [image]
4. open a new infopath designer form for your list

[image]

5. you may be prompted to update your columns on your form, select yes
6. publish the infopath form again

If you don't re-publish your infopath form with the updated column settings from sharepoint you'll most likely get an error. That's because they are out of sync.

Comment: Sorry for the very late response, but that dose not work @GettingPwnedBySharePoint